# How to get button width after it's layout visibility is changed from gone to visible

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

Have LinearLayout with few buttons in it.

Initially visibility is set to View.GONE but after user clicks, visibility is set to VISIBLE

This is where I need to programmatically detect one of button's width and match other button width to it.

initial call to

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

does not work since the this layout is initially not visible.

```
getMeasuredWdith() and getWidth()
```

return 0 when called after visibility flags has been changed.

Any ideas to get get width of this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

ended up going back to xml.

1. each row of buttons got their own LinearLayout.
2. wrapped all button rows in a parent LinearLayout.
3. Set parent and leading button (to which I'll be matching widths of other buttons) layout_width to "wrap_content"
4. Set other button rows' layout_widths to 'fill_parent'

done.